# How to avoid too much embedded if-else?

Tags: c++

like this:

```
if(...){
    if(...){
    }else{
       ...
    }
}else if(...){
    if(...){
    }else{
       ...
    }
}else{
    ...
}
```

in coding always meet with that situation, it looks so terrible. how to avoid it?

Comment: It depends a ***lot*** on the specifics. There's no general "do this" or "do that".

Comment: Exactly. The trick is to find a better way to do whatever it is you're doing. What that better way is depend on what you're doing.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that? You should show your actual code if you want any meaningful answer.

Comment: Splitting in sub methods may help also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general rule. but, two common cases are:

1. When a switch/case could help you reduce the amount of code.
2. When you should have designed your code with a state machine instead.

Depending on you needs and codes these might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you want to call some function depending upon result checked inside if-else ladder.

if you have a come with some index calculated with values you are checking inside the if-else condition, then having static array of function pointers could benefit you lot if ladder is too big.

eg.

```
uint8_t x;
uint8_t y;

if(x == 1)
{
  if (y == 1)
       call11();
  else if (y==2)
       call12();
}
else if( x == 2)
{
  if (y == 1)
       call21();
  else if (y==2)
       call22();
.
.
.
}
else if(x ==3)
.
.
.
```

Above code could be replaced as below

```
typedef void (*FuncPtr)();
FunPtr array[65535];

//intialize at once with some function
void initFunArray()
{
 array[1*256 + 1] = call11;
 array[1*256 + 2] = call12;
....
 array[2*256 + 1] = call21;
 array[2*256 + 2] = call22;
....
 array[3*256 + 1] = call31;
 array[3*256 + 2] = call32;
....
// Others will be set to null as array is static
}


uint8_t x;
uint8_t y;

index = x*256 + y;
array[index](); // calling appropriate call.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I see code like that I tend to wince a little. The worst case was a single file, 22 thousand lines long and only three functions - that made me sob.

The fact that at the lowest level you have a series of conditions which generally means some sort of type is involved.

So your code will look a bit like:

```
    If (...) {
       OnTypeConditionOne(...);
     Else if (...) {
       OnTypeConditionTwo(...);
     Else {
       OnTypeConditionThree(...);
     }
```

Obviously you pass through whatever variables are needed to perform the subclauses.  You then do the same to those subclauses until you have lots of small files. It is important to name the files something logical otherwise you might get lost in similar sounding names.